# Python's 'Requests' equivalent of 'curl -o'

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to download a pdf file from the internet. I am able to download it just fine using the following command:

```
curl -o test.pdf <url>
```

I tried to get it using 'Requests' but it failed. I did the following:

```
# Where <url> is the actual URL
r = requests.get(<url>, stream=True)
with open("test.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

What would be the exact equivalent to my curl command above?

Comment: `with open(test.pdf, 'wb') ` or `with open("test.pdf", 'wb') `, is typo?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, just edited. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `libcurl` has good python bindings ...

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content), this is how you should read->write a steam:

```
r = requests.get(<url>, stream=True)
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```